# Subspace of a Topological Space?

Tags: general-topology

So I found a question asking about Alexandrov Compactification- we originally had $(X,\mathcal{T})$ being a topological space- then we added a point $\{\infty\}$ not in the set $X$ and formed $C=X \cup \{\infty\}$. We then say let $\mathcal{T'}= \mathcal{T} \cup \{V\cup \{\infty\}| X \setminus V$ is closed and compact$  \}$ (so $V \in \mathcal{T}$). I can show that $\mathcal{T'}$ is a topology on $C$. 
However the next part then asks me to show that **$X$ is a subspace of $C$** and $C$ is compact. 
I thought only the compactness of C was the serious thing to prove here- I thought the thing in bold was just some obvious thing that stated but apparently not!- I thought $X$ is a subset of $C$- so it's a subspace of C no? What more could there be to this? Am I misundersterstanding something about what it means to be a subspace of a topological space?

***Please note** the compactness of $C$ is not an issue here- it's the bold bit which I foolishly realise has exposed a hole in my understanding of topology before my exam :(

Edit : *Also note I am aware of the term subspace topology*

Comment: Are you familiar with the phrase "subspace topology"?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes

Comment: Okay. If $(Y,\mathscr{T})$ is a topological space, and $Z\subset Y$, let $\mathscr{T}_Z$ denote the subspace topology on $Z$ induced by $\mathscr{T}$. Then $(Z,\mathscr{T}_Z)$ is called a (topological) subspace of $(Y,\mathscr{T})$. What you need to check is that the subspace topology on $X$ induced by $T'$ is just the original topology $T$. That's not hard to do, but it must be done.

Comment: @DanielFischer- Oh wonderful- thank you- yes that's pretty immediate- could you please tell me what that symbol for topology is and how I write it in Latex?

Comment: It's `\mathscr{T}`, another common font choice for topologies (and other things) is `\mathcal{T}`, giving $\mathcal{T}$.

Answer (score 1):

So what you need to show is that $\mathscr{T}'$ restricted to $X \subseteq C$ equals the topology $\mathscr{T}$ on $X$ that we started with.

This is quite easy to see: by construction $\mathscr{T} \subseteq \mathscr{T}'$, so all open sets of $X$ are still open, and if $O \in \mathscr{T}'$, either $O \in \mathscr{T}$, so $O \cap X = O \in \mathscr{T}$, or $O = \{\infty\} \cup (X \setminus V)$, where $V$ is compact and closed in $X$, and then $O \cap X = X \setminus V$ which is in $\mathscr{T}$ as $V$ is closed. So for $\mathscr{T}'$ restricted to $X$ does not contain more open sets than $X$ had, so we have equality.

The compactness of $V$ is needed for the compactness of $C$, the closedness of $C$ (which is *not* automatic for compact $C$ if $X$ is not Hausdorff!) is needed to ensure that $X$ is still a subspace (or else the complement of a non-closed compact set of $X$ would be open in the subspace topology from $C$, but not open originally). For a compactification we do not want to modify the original topology of the compactified space, it needs to embed as a subspace.